# D3 Transitions on SVG markers

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, marker, transition

I'm plotting arrows in an SVG, using `svg:line` elements with markers defined as follows:

```
    svg_.append("svg:defs")
        .append("svg:marker")
        .attr("id", "bluearrowhead")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 0)
        .attr("refY", 0)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 6)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")
        .attr("fill", "deepskyblue");
```

I want to be able to fade out my arrows. For the arrow shafts, this works:

```
    svg_.selectAll(".arrows")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .style("stroke-opacity", 0.0)
        .remove();
```

But whilst the shafts fade, the arrowheads stay for 1000ms then suddenly disappear. I've tried `fill-opacity` on the lines, and tried `selectAll` on `.bluearrowhead` but to no avail. Is there any way to transition the marker styles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
svg_.selectAll(".arrows")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("opacity", 0.0)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks - didn't know about the `opacity` property for the whole element.